# frequency distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I'm not familiar with probability.

Say I have some n data points over the reals $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathbb{R}$ such as the distance to the basket during a field goal attempt. How should I construct a distribution over the real line to fit this data?

Say I pick the normal distribution (not sure about the connection to the data). How can I measure the probability that a new data point z will exist according to my distribution?

Certainly, to get a positive probability, I must pick a neighborhood around the data point. But my probability then depends on the width of the neighborhood...

Do I need to make the domain discrete?

Comment: The phrase "probability that a new data point $z$ will exist" is vague. Do you mean the probability of getting the value $z$ given your data?

Comment: the probability given the data I guess. btw, maybe you could construct a histogram but I don't understand how to set the width of the bars.

Comment: Setting bar width in histograms is something of an art form: I'd go for about 15 bars to 30 bars, but that's not a hard-and-fast rule. You could use your histogram to calculate probabilities.

Comment: Oh, and try not to let any data point fall right on the boundary between any two bars.

Comment: how do you calculate probabilities with a histogram? is it (height of bar)/(sum of all heights)?

Comment: I would first figure out which bar your $z$ falls in, and then do exactly what you described.

Comment: Should I construct the histogram on the training data or the whole data set? I'm still confused as to how to measure the probability from a smoothed distribution such as a normal distribution..

Comment: You should construct the histogram on the training data, because that's the only data you should be making any inferences from. Splitting the data into training and test is to help you assess your model's fit, so it doesn't make sense to look at the test data (which is in the whole data) while building your model. Additionally, for a continuous distribution like the normal distribution, considering the probability that a certain point (z) exists makes no sense. What you can measure is the likelihood you see something as extreme as z (z or greater).